# Complex Query in shell

Tags: shell, debian

I have a file with many entries like

```
1365593957.914 172.27.15.16 593
1365593969.237 172.27.15.31 1149
1365593979.239 172.27.15.33 5696
1365593989.242 172.27.15.31 1338
1365593999.344 172.27.15.33 21406
```

These are timestamp ip datasize.

I need sum of all datasizes for each ip if timestamp is in between `$tp1` and `$tp2`. I tried readind file line by line and then applying awk on each line to check range of timestamp but it did not work. Also, I have no idea how to add these up categorically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -v tp1=$tp1 -v tp2=$tp2 '$1 > tp1 && $1 < tp2 {
    total[$2] += $3;
}
END {
    for (ip in total)
         print "IP:", ip, "=>", total[ip];
}'
```

seems simple enough. If that doesn't work for you, in what way doesn't it work?

*EDIT: Reformatted. Indentation is being ignored, don't know why.*

Explanation:

- `-v tp1=$tp1` means "create variable in awk named *tp1* with the value of the shell variable named *tp1*.
- `$1 > tp1 && $1 < tp2` means "only execute this code block if the value of the first field is larger than the value of *tp1* and smaller than the value of *tp2*.
- `total[$2] += $3;` uses the value of the second field (the IP address) as an array index into an implicitly declared array named "tota", and adds the value of the third field.
- AWK will iterate over all records in the input, with the default record being a single line of text. For each record, the above code will be executed if the condition is valid.
- `END` identifies a code block that is executed after all records have been processed, instead of being executed against every (matching) input record.
- `for (ip in total)` identifies another iterator: For each value stored in the array named `total`, assign the name of the array index to the variable named `ip`, and execute the associated code block.
- In this case, the associated code block is `print "IP:", ip, "=>", total[ip];`, which prints the string "IP:", a space, the value if the variable named `ip` (which is an IP address, used as an array index name), another space, the string "=>", *yet* another space, and the value stored in the array `total` indexed by the IP address.

Any questions?

Comment: Reformatted. A proper explanation won't fit in a comment, do you still need it?

Comment: If you can explain it without comments too, that would work. Thank you!!